# org.apache.poi: POIFSFileSystem is not assignable to NPOIFSFileSystem on new new HSSFWorkbook() on Linux

Tags: apache-poi

Getting an exception when just creating a new HSSFWorkbook object using poi 3.17 on Linux but the same code works on Windows. Using Redhat Linux 7.6 and openjdk version "1.8.0_181". The same code works find on Windows.

I've tried everything I can thing of without success.

The code is pretty trivial:

```
public RenderForXLS(RendererProperties rendererProperties) throws MOException
{
    locale = rendererProperties.getLocale();
    log.debug("Locale == " + locale);
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    normalFont = createFont(workbook, HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex(), false);
    boldFont = createFont(workbook, HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex(), true);
    headerCellStyle = createHeaderCellStyle(workbook);
    dataCellStyle = createDataCellStyle(workbook);
    doubleNumericCellStyle = createDoubleNumericCellStyle(workbook);
    integerNumericCellStyle = createIntegerNumericCellStyle(workbook);
    percentageCellStyle = createPercentageCellStyle(workbook);
}


java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 172
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/poi/POIDocument.getPropertySet(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/EncryptionInfo;)Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/PropertySet; @172: astore
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem' (current frame, locals[4]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem' (stack map, locals[4])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @94
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/poi/POIDocument', 'java/lang/String', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/EncryptionInfo', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/cryptoapi/CryptoAPIDecryptor' }
    stack: { 'java/io/IOException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @172
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/poi/POIDocument', 'java/lang/String', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/EncryptionInfo', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode', 'org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'java/io/IOException' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 4e01 3a04 1225 3a05 2cc6 0057
    0x0000010: 2cb6 0026 9900 5012 273a 052a b600 283a
    0x0000020: 062d 1906 b600 299a 0024 bb00 2a59 bb00
    0x0000030: 1959 b700 1a12 2bb6 001b 1906 b600 1b12
    0x0000040: 2cb6 001b b600 1eb7 002d bf2c b600 2ec0
    0x0000050: 002f 3a07 1907 2d19 06b6 0030 3a04 1904
    0x0000060: b600 054e 2dc6 000b 2d2b b600 299a 000e
    0x0000070: 013a 0619 04b8 0031 1906 b012 253a 052d
    0x0000080: 2d2b b600 32b6 0033 3a06 1234 3a05 1906
    0x0000090: b800 353a 0719 06b6 0036 1904 b800 3119
    0x00000a0: 07b0 3a08 1906 b600 3619 08bf 3a06 1906
    0x00000b0: bf3a 06bb 0021 59bb 0019 59b7 001a 1238
    0x00000c0: b600 1b19 05b6 001b 1239 b600 1b2b b600
    0x00000d0: 1bb6 001e 1906 b700 3abf 3a09 1904 b800
    0x00000e0: 3119 09bf
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [138, 149] => handler: 162
    bci [162, 164] => handler: 162
    bci [12, 115] => handler: 172
    bci [123, 154] => handler: 172
    bci [162, 172] => handler: 172
    bci [12, 115] => handler: 177
    bci [123, 154] => handler: 177
    bci [162, 172] => handler: 177
    bci [12, 115] => handler: 218
    bci [123, 154] => handler: 218
    bci [162, 220] => handler: 218
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@75,{Object[#178],Object[#157],Object[#179],Object[#180],Object[#181],Object[#157],Object[#157]},{})
    chop_frame(@100,1)
    same_frame(@112)
    same_frame(@123)
    full_frame(@162,{Object[#178],Object[#157],Object[#179],Object[#180],Object[#181],Object[#157],Object[#182]},{Object[#183]})
    full_frame(@172,{Object[#178],Object[#157],Object[#179],Object[#180],Object[#181],Object[#157]},{Object[#159]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@177,Object[#184])
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@218,Object[#183])

        at com.sas.analytics.mo.services.report.RenderForXLS.<init>(RenderForXLS.java:82)
```

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of Apache POI on your classpath. Remove the old jars and it ought to be fine, though upgrading to the latest Apache POI is recommended!

Comment: I unzipped and checked all the jars. There is only one poi.jar and only one HSSFWorkbook.class file. The poi jars are poi, poi-excelant, poi-ooxml.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas, and poi-scratchpad. The manifest shows 3.17 for all versions. I did notice in the manifest for the poi files that they were created with Java 1.6, Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.). We we running Java 1.8. Is that a possible issue?

Comment: Nope, jars compiled for older Java versions are fine. You'll need to check elsewhere on your classpath, somewhere it looks like you've got an old copy of Apache POI, even if you didn't mean to!